# What is the (parametric) intersection of a plane and a sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can someone please show me how to prove that the intersection of the plane

$$x+y+z=0$$  and the sphere

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

can be expressed as

$$x(t)=\frac{\cos t-\sqrt3 \cdot\sin t}{\sqrt6}$$

$$y(t)=\frac{\cos t+\sqrt3 \cdot\sin t}{\sqrt6}$$

$$z(t)=\frac{-2\cos t}{\sqrt6}$$

Ps: Also, why am I not getting the correct notation? I am using a macbook pro (safari) if that is a concern?

Comment: Notation should not depend on the machine you're using, since it's MathJax.  You did have some / where you should have \.

Comment: I find it strange that the intersection of two objects in $\mathbb R^3$ would be a path in $\mathbb R$. In other words, are we looking for $y$ and $z$ of $t$ as well?

Comment: @Milind: I'm afraid you have edited it *wrong*, check out the original version.

Comment: I know how to find the intersection by simply equating these equations which gives me $$x^2+y^2+xy=\frac{1}{2}$$ but i don't know what the next step is?... @BradyTrainor

Comment: Thankyou @Inceptio , the correct equation is now up :)

Comment: @BradyTrainor Sorry, the full question is now up, i didnt think that y and z mattered in the question but i realised it was giving the wrong question, apologies guys.

Comment: @amanda, I ran into that $xy$ term as well. Perhaps if I had studied conics a bit more... I smelled an ellipse, but it looks like vadim123 has spotted the nice substitution below.

Comment: @amanda, do you know some linear algebra? If so, rather than messing with these ellipses, it's easier to rotate the coordinate system so that in the new $x'y'z'$ coordinates, the plane $x+y+z=0$ becomes $z'=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve for $z=-x-y$ and plug in $x^2+y^2+(-x-y)^2=1$, which rearranges to $2x^2+2xy+2y^2=1$.  Hence for any fixed $z$ you have a rotated ellipse.

Let $u=(x+y/2)$.  Then $u^2=x^2+xy+y^2/4$, so the equation becomes $2u^2+\frac{3}{2}y^2=1$.  In standard form this is:  $$\frac{u^2}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}})^2}=1$$

We can solve this parametrically as $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t$, $$y=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cos t$$  We can now find $$x=u-y/2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\cos t$$ and $$z=-x-y=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t +(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}})\cos t$$

Alas, you posted your revisions after I'd made my choices so my solution will not agree with yours.  There are three choices at the first step (solve for $z,y,x$), and two choices at the second step (replace $x$ or $y$).  One of those six choices might give the result you have.  :-)

Followup: A cross term ($xy$) is a rotation and can always be eliminated by a change of variables, pointing in the directions of the major and minor axes.  There is a systematic way to do this; see [here](http://www.maa.org/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html) or [here](http://www.mecca.org/~halfacre/math/rotation.htm), or you can do it by the seat of your pants, like I did.  I didn't directly rotate, instead I sheared, which made the computations a bit simpler.

Edit: fix sign error, thanks @Mhenni.

Edit 2: add general method

Comment: Wow, Thankyou so much @vadim123 . i understand everything but I am little confused as to how you got $$u=\frac{(x-y)}{2}$$ ?
Also, I think that should be a plus? But what I dont understand is why you let $$u=\frac{(x-y)}{2}$$ ?

Comment: It should be $ 2x^2+2xy+2y^2=1 $. The sign of $xy$.

Comment: (In the first sentence)

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I cannot tag him so I am unsure if vadim123 can see my comment but I am unsure as to why Vadim let $$u=x-\frac{y}{2}$$ ?

Comment: That substitution is a change of variables that undoes the rotation of the ellipse.  There are many others, such as $u=y-\frac{x}{2}$, and also the symmetric one @Brady offers.

Comment: @vadim123 Ok, I am sort of understanding it. Maybe answering this question will help me understand it, so why didn't we let $$u=x^2 + y^2$$ ?

Comment: Yeah my substitution isn't as slick as I was hoping. Perhaps more insight can be gathered if one take the matrix point of view on the transformation of conics. I couldn't find a nice treatment on the internet.

Comment: @amanda, the goal in the substitution is to still have an ellipse, but to no longer have a cross term.  If we let $u=x^2+y^2$, the equation becomes $2u+2xy=1$.  Not only is this not an ellipse, but you haven't eliminated anything (there are now 3 variables).

Comment: @BradyTrainor, see my links (especially 2nd).

Comment: Not to sound old or anything, but rotation of conic sections to kill the cross term was a standard part of the course when I took calculus 25 years ago.  Every once in a blue moon it comes in handy. :-)

Comment: Thankyou so much Vadim! :) It took me a while to respond because I was trying to understand it and now I do. Thankyou so much for your  patience and effort :) @vadim123

Answer (score 1):

(Originally I had $u,v=x+y,x-y$, but after going through half the problem, I considered that $2u,2v=x+y,x-y$ would be a little more convenient.)

amanda, after your substitution, we consider $x^2+xy+y^2={1\over2}$.

Here are is a nice choice for the next substitution,

\begin{align}
2u&=x+y,\\
2v&=x-y.
\end{align}

We next consider

\begin{align}
4u^2&=x^2+y^2+2xy,\\
4v^2&=x^2+y^2-2xy.
\end{align}

To get $x^2+y^2+xy$, we need $2u^2+2v^2+(u^2-v^2)$. Thus our problem is transformed to

$$6u^2+2v^2=1.$$

Then we have parametric solutions

$$u=\sqrt{1\over6}\cos t,\ v=\sqrt{1\over2}\sin t.$$

From there, we find for instance

$$x=u+v={\cos t+\sqrt3\sin t\over\sqrt6},$$

and the rest should be straightforward.

To get the sign to match what is shown in your equations, I can think of several ways to go.

- You could simply note the symmetry in $x$ and $y$ and switch them (which suggests that if we had made the substitution $2v=y-x$ instead of $x-y$, that would have worked also).
- From $6u^2+2v^2=1$, we could have chosen $v=-\sqrt{1\over2}\sin t$.
- If we make the substitution $t=-s$, then we have $x={\cos (-s)+\sqrt3\sin (-s)\over\sqrt6}={\cos s-\sqrt3\sin s\over\sqrt6}$. Now, call it $t$ again.

Comment: ohhhh I absolutely understand this now! Thankyou so much Brady, I couldn't of understood it without the help of you and Vadim. It feels so good understand it, thankyou so much :)

Comment: Glad to help. I think the $xy$ term motivated a little "creativity".

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Brady but how did you get $2u^2+2v^2-(u^2-v^2)$. simplifying to 

$$6u^2+2v^2=1.$$  ?

Comment: also, shouldn't it be  $2u^2+2v^2+(u^2-v^2)$

Comment: @amanda, yes, you are right about the sign error. That gives coefficients of 3 and 1, which after clearing the fractions in the original equation, becomes the coefficients of 6 and 2.

Comment: Sorry i am little lost now. What do you mean by "clearing the fractions in the original equation"? How does that bring about 6 and 2?

Comment: oh right, after substituting it in lol silly question by me. Thankyou :))

Comment: Lastly, what do you mean by substitute s=-t? Is it possible if you could edit the example if it's not too much to ask? After that step, I  think i have mastered any difficulty given by this question :) @BradyTrainor

Comment: @amanda, I have added some ideas to the end.

Comment: Thankyou Brady, I really needed that part :)